# Factorising n! fitting $x^\frac{n}{k}$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Prove: There exist real numbers a,b, such that 1<a<b and for any integer $n\ge 2$, there exist positive integers $x_1\ge x_2\ge ...\ge x_{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}$such that $n!=\Pi_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}x_k$ and $x_k\in (a^\frac{n}{k},b^{\frac{n}{k}})$.

I've tried to list all the prime factors of n! but that's too complicated. Notice that the function $x^\frac{n}{k}$ is too strange. It means there are many small factors and a few large factors.

Comment: Where does this question come from? Do you have any reason to think it's true?

Comment: It's from another person who thinks it's true and wants a solution.

Comment: OP, perhaps, pass @GerryMyerson's q. to that "another person", then pass their answer to us. Or else, answer the Gerry's q. yourself, please.

Comment: I feel that the key to the solution is the approximation $\ n! \sim (n/e)^n\ $ or possibly its improvements as the Stirling formula, etc. This seem to direct a solution in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your initial guess about prime factors can produce a solution. More precisely, it is known that
$$
n!=\prod_{p\leq n} p^{v_p(n!)},
$$
where the product is taken over prime numbers and
$$
v_p(n!)=\left[\frac{n}{p}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{p^2}\right]+\ldots
$$
Let now for any $1\leq k\leq n/2$
$$
x_k=\prod_{\alpha, p: p^\alpha\leq n/k}p.
$$
The product is over prime values of $p$ and positive integers $\alpha$. The inequality $x_{k}\geq x_{k+1}$ is trivial. Product of all $x_k$ is equal to $n!$ by the factorisation above: the factor $p$ that corresponds to a given $d=p^\alpha$ appears in $x_k$ for $d\leq n/k$, there are $\left[\frac{n}{p^\alpha}\right]$ such $k$. This means that
$$
\prod_k x_k=\prod_{\alpha,p} p^{\left[\frac{n}{p^\alpha}\right]}=\prod_{p\leq n} p^{v_p(n!)}=n!,
$$
as needed. Finally, let $\Lambda(d)$ denote the von Mangoldt function, i.e. $\Lambda(d)=\ln p$ if $d=p^\alpha$ for some $p$ and $\alpha$ and $\Lambda(d)=0$ otherwise. Then we clearly have
$$
\ln x_k=\sum_{d\leq n/k} \Lambda(d)=\psi(n/k).
$$
Here $\psi(x)$ is Chebyshev's psi function, the summatory function of $\Lambda$. It is well-known that there are $c,C>0$ such that for $x\geq 2$ we have
$$
cx\leq \psi(x)\leq Cx.
$$
In particular, one can take $1<a<e^c$, $b>e^C$ and get the desired bound:
$$
a^{n/k}\leq \exp(\psi(n/k))=x_k\leq b^{n/k}.
$$